# Convert height Geoid EGM96 to ellipsoidal?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I'd like to convert the height data which is in EGM96 to Orthometric projection.

Perhaps there are tools, like ArgGIS (I cannot find if ArcGIS can do this), or any formula that may help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ERDAS Imagine Coordinate Tools.